# Find My iPhone - location services

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone, geolocation

I've been checking system services within my location services regularly and have noticed the grey arrow by the side of Find My iPhone (FMIP). I understand this means it was accessed in the last 24 hrs.

If I used FMIP to locate my daughter through her email address the arrow appears in location services only and not within system services. From what I can tell the only time the arrow appears against FMIP in system services is if someone has logged in to my own FMIP using my email and password, is that correct?

Presuming no apps or anything used FMIP as they would need to know my password and email, I am concerned my ex is tracking my location. I have changed my password but it's still happening.

Is my understanding of how the arrows work correct? If not can someone clarify for me.

[image]