# Find My constantly using location services

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone, geolocation

On my iPhone in settings under privacy->system services. Find my iPhone always has the grey navigation arrow next to it, It has been like this for over a week. 3 days ago I noticed that find my iPhone was actively using my location (purple arrow) at 5 in the morning so i changed the password to my iCloud account and haven't logged into iCloud on any of my other devices(MacBook/apple watch).

Its been 3 days since I changed my password but "find my iphone" still has a grey navigation compass arrow next to it.

I was wondering if there is any way to see who/what is using "find my iPhone" to view my location?

My question is very similar to this one: [Find My iPhone - location services](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371364/find-my-iphone-location-services)

Comment: Unless I’m reading your question wrong, Find My *must* use location services.  Its designed to keep updated as to where your device(s) are; this is normal behavior.

Comment: @Allan I have all the location sharing features off, if im not actively looking for my device. why does "Find My" need to "keep updates as to where your devices(s) are"? this is not behavior i noticed with previous versions of IOS

Comment: It has to.  It can help ypu find your device even if offline because it has a history of where it’s been.  It’s a requirement of the feature: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210515. You are probably confusing it with the old “Find My Phone.”

Comment: Additionally, Location Services runs constantly, apps & other services generate that arrow icon when they ask Location Services for a current location [which LS already knows]. If you disabled any app from LS, it wouldn't stop LS, it would only stop that app from being able to ask LS.